# SharePoint Image Map Tooltips

Tags: 2013

[image]I've created a clickable USA map in SharePoint. Now, I'm attempting to insert tooltips for all states. A buddy hinted I could use the 'title attribute' to achieve this. However, he didn't tell me where to or how to enter code. I'm an amateur and new to SharePoint coding; so, if someone would please provide step by step instructions for SharePoint Classic 2013? Do I enter the title attribute in the html code for the web part?

Comment: Hi Pamela, can you provide the code that you used for your map. This way we can suggest something.

Comment: Thanks @DenisMolodtsov I've added a picture to main post.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show a tooltip, you can use the `title` HTML attribute attribute

For example:

```
<area title="Texas" href="...">
...
```

This is another example:

```
<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm" title="computer!">
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm" title="phone!">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Cup of coffee" href="coffee.htm"  title="coffee!">
</map>
```

[image]